# Time.timeScale = 0f; not pausing my game when I run it in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am trying to make a script for a pause menu and I try to use `Time.timeScale` and it doesn't pause the game when I run it in unity. I have another script that is a game over script and it also uses the `Time.timeScale = 0f;` and it works fine when I run it. I checked in the Debug.Log for the TimetimsScale and it stayed at 1. This is my code:

```
void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
    {
        
        if (gamePaused)
        {
            Play();
        }
        else
        {
            Paused();
        }
    }
}

public void Paused ()
{
    gamePaused = true;
    pauseMenu.SetActive(true);
    Time.timeScale = 0f;
}
public void Play()
{
    Time.timeScale = 1f;
    pauseMenu.SetActive(false);
    gamePaused = false;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I see you are using the [tag:unityscript] tag, please note that this is (as explained in the tag info) a deprecated scripting language made by Unity, and not an encompassing term for all scripts in Unity. Your question is about C# (and I have removed the tag for you). Please only use this tag if you're working on legacy code using the actual language UnityScript. This keeps the question and tags in line with each other :)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `doesn't work`? What exactly is the expected behavior and where/how does it behave different?

Comment: On what object is this script placed? Component must be placed on an active GameObject and be enabled in order for `Update` to be called. Please check these conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find any logical errors in your posted code. So there are two possibilities.

1. Somewhere in your code also controlled `Time.timeScale`. You should check references of it. or check it's value directly by using `Debug.Log` Function.
   And also it can happen if your script is added twice (or never added). Check your script's reference by right clicking your script file in project tab and select `Find References In Scene`.
2. Your logic may not be controlled by `Time.timeScale`.

First of all, `Time.timeScale = 0f;` doesn't mean everything gonna be stopped.

It affect just the logic that about 'Time' (`Time.deltaTime`, Animation Sequence, `WaitForSeconds` class, etc)

For example, If you using `Update` Function (or `yield retun null` loop Coroutine) without `Time.deltaTime`, That will not stop with timeScale zero.

Comment: This answer has it correct, but to add a little bit ot it: As WonJae stated your `update` will not be affected by setting `Time.timeScale = 0` except where you use `Time.DeltaTime` in it. What you can do is use `FixedUpdate` instead, which will be stopped when you set the timescale to 0 ([as stated in the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html)). Additionally when setting the timeScale it is adviced to also set the `Time.fixedDeltaTime` to the same amount too.